# Upload/Send file to Facebook via Send Api Reference using python requests

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, facebook-send-api

I am trying to upload a file to Facebook send API via python requests. Curl to send API request is as follows

```
curl  \
  -F 'recipient={"id":"<PSID>"}' \
  -F 'message={"attachment":{"type":"<ASSET_TYPE>", "payload":{"is_reusable":true}}}' \
  -F 'filedata=@/tmp/shirt.png;type=image/png' \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

I'm referring to [this facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/#file)

I have tried the API using python requests

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/us092.pgm')
with open('temp.jpg', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(r.content)

files = {
    'recipient': (None, '{"id":" <USER_ID>"}'),
    'message': (None, '{"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{"is_reusable":true}}}'),
    'filedata': ('temp.jpg', open('temp.jpg', 'rb')),
}
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/messages"
params = {"access_token":"<ACCESS_TOKEN>"}

response = requests.post(url=url,params=params, files=files)
print(response.content)
```

I'm getting response as follows

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Upload attachment failure.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018047,"fbtrace_id":"Atv2YqLlb4ABkoVOW4sgnzd"}}
```

Following is the description of the error code

[image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: is it now possible to read direct messages of account that is using Send API app to analyze the DMs??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `;type=image/png` to `temp.jpg` at `filedata` key.
This should look like:

```
'filedata': ('temp.jpg;type=image/png', open('temp.jpg', 'rb')),
```

Comment: Tried it, but the API still throws the same error